# Searching for existence of multiple values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a better(pythonic) way of achieving the below result. Looking for existence of multiple values in a list of dictionary items.

I think the below solution not scalable, if I have to match for more items in a dictionary.

```
>>> mylist=[{'fruit':'apple', 'quantity':'200'},{'fruit':'orange', 'quantity':'300'},{'fruit':'apple', 'quantity':'100'}]
>>> a = 'apple'
>>> b = '200'
>>> for i in mylist:
...     if a in i.values() and b in i.values(): print(a,b)
...     
... 
apple 200
```

Comment: Besides searching for their existence, it looks like you also want to print out all of the ones found, correct? Is that a requirement?

Comment: "Looking for existence of a key:value". you never test the existence of keys, only values

Comment: @martineau print as an example in the code. I would replace `print` with `append` the item to a list.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Good point, that is correct. Not checking for keys in this case.  I don't expect keys changing much in my use case, I think checking values is good for now. Will update the  original question.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Why is the data stored like this? Where does it come from?

Comment: Also, please don't post the code in your update as something that's being executed line-by-line at the Python console — make it a real script.

Comment: What about `[mydict['fruit']+' '+mydict['quantity'] for mydict in mylist if mydict['fruit'] == a and mydict['quantity'] == b]`? You already know the names of the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if `{a,b}` is a subset of the set made with the values of each dictionary.

```
if any({a,b}.issubset(set(d.values())) for d in mylist):
   print('found')
```

Comment: Isn't this quite inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This should do the trick in 1 line:

```
mylist=[{'fruit':'apple', 'quantity':'200'},{'fruit':'orange', 'quantity':'300'},{'fruit':'apple', 'quantity':'100'}]

a = "apple"
b = "200"

print ''.join(['{0} {1}'.format(a, b) for li in mylist if a in li.values() and b in li.values()])

>>> apple 200
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information in order to find an ideal solution. The current example you shared is too simplistic to be very useful.

Until then, here is how I would modify that toy example:

```py
fruit_tuples = [('apple', 200), ('orange', 300), ('apple', 100)]

targ_tuple = ('apple', 200)

for curr_tuple in fruit_tuples:
    if curr_tuple == targ_tuple:
        print(curr_tuple)
```

Output:

```
('apple', 200)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple pythonic way based on *list comprehensions*. You just have to format the output as you want.

```
>>> [(a, b) for i in mylist if a in i.values() and b in i.values()]
[('apple', '200')]
```

I also check this compact version and It works:

```
>>> [(a, b) for i in mylist if (a and b) in i.values()]
[('apple', '200')]
```

Comment: I doubt the `if (a and b)` part does what you think it does…

Comment: No this does not work my friend. Operation `(a and b)` results to `"200"` and then it is only checking if `"200"'` is present in `i.values` which result to `True`.  Just try printing the value of  '(a and b)` and you will understand.

Comment: When you write *(a and b)* with parentheses, it is the two values that will be checked. *a and b in i.values()* is different to *(a and b) in i.values()*. You can check with your Terminal.